# ¿Cómo puedo entender la palabra reservada Continue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos, me estoy iniciando en el mundo de Python y la palabra resevar "continue" me está generando dudas. En ese ejemplo tenemos un ciclo "while" por el cual nos dice que si el input "numero" es distinto de -1 continuamos con el "if". Pero cuando el "if" es -1 se aplica el "continue". Eso es lo que genera mucha confusión, ya que no sé si al aplicarse el "continue" pasa a "contador =  1" o pasa al siguiente "if".

Comment: `continue` se salta todo y vuelve al inicio del bucle, a diferencia de `pass` que solobomite lo que este en su bloque

Comment: @christian Bueno, realmente `pass` no omite nada. `pass` es solo un placeholder. No hace absolutamente nada más que estar en un lugar dado para, por ejemplo, evitar errores de sintaxis al tener funciones sin cuerpo.

Comment: @revliscano verdad, había amplificado esa situación y mi comentario fue incorrecto,

Comment: Lectura urgente: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en un bucle (sea while o for) se aplica la palabra "continue", el bucle se interrumpe justo ahí y pasa a la siguiente iteración.

El siguiente código te puede ayudar a entender como funciona "continue":

```
for i in range(100):
    if(i > 50 and i < 75):
        print("continue")
        # El código dentro del bucle for para de ejecutarse justo aqui y se pasa al siguente item del iterable, en este caso i+1
        continue
    print(i)
```

En este código cuando i es mayor a 50 y menor a 75 se ejecuta el continue. Esto hace que la linea `print(i)` no se ejecute, ya que el bucle se interrumpe antes. Aun así, el valor de i sigue aumentando 1 en 1.

En base a esto, respondiendo a tu pregunta, ninguno de los dos. NO salta al siguiente if NI aplica contador=1.

Hice mi mejor esfuerzo para explicarlo, cualquier cosa que no entiendas dime c:

Comment: oohh!! o:! Entonces como en el primer "if" no se cumple el "numero = -1" el "continue" no se aplica y pasa directamente a la variable contador :3 Muchas gracias.